# create a page on a specific folder get cli | Getx Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, get-cli

I have installed the get_cli for my flutter development.  As the docs say, I use the command `get create page:home` to create a home module with bindings, view and controller. **It is created in the lib/app/modules/home** folder by default. How to create this under a differnet folder, say **lib/app2/modules/home** or **lib/modules/home**.

Answer (score 2):

have u tried this:

```
get create page:home on lib/modules/home
```

Answer (score 0):

with command below, get cli automatically creates new pages in `/lib/module` directory

```
get create page:mypage
```

So if I want to create a subdirectory in home/bedroom
so it's

```
get create page:bedroom on home
```

For more details visit --> [get_cli](https://pub.dev/packages/get_cli)

Comment: What's the difference between this suggestion and [@Abdelrahman Tareq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66929718/3025856) from April?

Comment: The difference is that I'm specifying here that it's not just the home directory. You can create your page in the folder of your choice.
A little self-explanatory !

Comment: That seems implicit in @Abdelrahman's answer, given that they used the OP's proposed `lib/modules/home` directory (which _is_ the folder of the OP's choice).